# Not able access multiple data sources in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring & Spring boot and I am trying to access two data sources but am I able to connect to only one data source.

when I try to call a function accessing 2nd data source the call goes to the first data source and I get the below error,

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'testify.test' doesn't exist

I have followed the below tutorials for multi DB access and my code is similar to the code in **Roufid** link,

1. [Roufid](http://roufid.com/spring-boot-multiple-databases-configuration/)
2. [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

***Can someone point out what i am missing or where I am doing a mistake*** ?

below are the code files,

**AConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "aEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "aTransactionManager",
basePackages = "test.serv")
public class AConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.adb")
public DataSource aDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="aEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntManFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder build) {
    return build.dataSource(aDataSource()).persistenceUnit("aPU").build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="aTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("aEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory enManFact) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(enManFact);
}
}
```

**BConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "bEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "bTransactionManager",
basePackages = "test.serv")
public class BConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.bdb")
public DataSource bDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name="bEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntManFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder build) {
    return build.dataSource(bDataSource()).persistenceUnit("bPU").build();
}

@Bean(name="bTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("bEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory enManFact) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(enManFact);
}
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
     version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="aPU"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="bPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Service.java**

```
public interface Service extends CrudRepository<X, Integer> {
@Query(value = "select y from test where x = :x", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findByName(@Param("x") String x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have your Repository classes (`Service`) in the same package

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "bEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "bTransactionManager",
basePackages = "test.serv")
```

**basePackages = "test.serv"**

Move it into seprate packages. That should work

Comment: that worked !! how did you know that was the mistake ?

Comment: SO says I can only accept after 4 mins..so will accept in few mins..ohh thanks :)
do you know any site or any tutorial where i can find the do and dont's in spring ?